# Alternative to Sumatra PDF

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a minimal PDF viewer similar to Sumatra PDF for Windows.

I want:

- Quick start-up time
- No interface clutter
- Supports bookmarks
- Allows collapsing/expanding all bookmarks (with a single click, not by clicking each one individually)

Comment: Why not use Sumatra PDF?

Comment: suggesting [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/)

Comment: @unforgettableid Doesn't have last feature.

Comment: @MasihAkbari Not minimal.

Answer (score 5):

I can ***highly recommend*** [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads).

It is nothing short of superb.  It has quick start-up time, a completely customizable user interface (as much or as little clutter as you like), supports bookmarks, and allows collapsing/expanding of bookmarks.

It also happens to be gratis (free of cost), totally portable, and of exceptionally high quality.  It is not open-source.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not sure for what platform you are asking, for now I can only give you the advise to take a look at **http://pdfreaders.org/**:

It's a list of FLOSS PDF readers for all platforms; and most of them are really lightweight and quick with all basic functions.

---

If you are looking for only free (not open source) readers I can recommend:

- [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (for Windows only)
- [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) (for Windows and Linux)
- [Perfect PDF Reader](http://de.soft-xpansion.eu/products/freeware/reader/) (for Windows only)

They all got a huge amount of functions and therefore they are not so lightweight as nearly all of http://pdfreaders.org/, but still lighter than the Adobe reader! ;-)

Comment: The question is tagged "[tag:windows]".  :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads) for Microsoft Windows these days.

Licence: GPLv2+

- Quick start-up time: < 1 sec
- No interface clutter: Menu + 1 line. Thumbnails sidebar which can be hidden or used to show bookmarks.
- Supports bookmarks: Yes
- Allows collapsing/expanding all bookmarks: Bookmarks in menu.

Comment: Is evince being developed for Windows any longer?